# Synchronize async calls within a for loop in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have two mongo models. The User model contains a field 'groups', which is an array and contains all the group ids that the user is a member of. The Groups model has all the information regarding the group like group name, owner etc. I want to fetch an array of all the user's groups and include details like 'group name' and 'group owner' in the response.

Please Note: I have two calls which are asynchronous. All the code below is within another post method.

```
//First Async Call
    User.getGroupsByUsername(req.user.username, (err, groups) => {
                let userGroups = [];
                for (let group of groups) {
                    temp.group_id = group.group_id;
                    temp.role = group.role;
//Second Async call within for loop
                    User.getGroupsDetails(group_id, (err, groupInfo) => {
                        temp.group_name = groupInfo.name;
                        temp.group_owner = groupInfo.owner;
                    });
//temp.group_name and temp.group_owner are still unassigned because of async call
                    userGroups.push(temp);
                    temp = null;
                }
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    groups: userGroups
                });
            });
```

When the code above gets to `userGroups.push(temp);` `userGroups` and `temp` are undefined (see code comments).

I tried manipulating the queries, but mongo aggregate doesn't seem to produce results in the format I require, That would be a whole another topic. I want to know how we can produce such a response using node.js. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use async/await

Comment: why not to use multi: true and $in ? And for-off for sets not for arrays

Comment: `User.getGroupsDetails(group_id, (err, groupInfo) => { ... } <-- needs );`

Comment: @AyushGupta Can you please specify how exactly? I tried async/await on getGroupDetails, but the result doesn't load the values.

Comment: @Archer Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it here, but that's not the problem.